# How to Edit some variable in macro formula

Tags: excel, vba, replace, default-value

```
Sub Import_B1S()
Sheets("B1S").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;E:\DANDY\FBI\ATM\Prima\ATM\1.Transaksi\Data Mentah\**191023**RPT\191023B1S-RAW.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
        )
        .Name = "B1S"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

The question:

I want to change 191023 automatically with other number,example 191024
and that other number its get from cells,example sheets A1
so the value of 191042 can change according from user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dim sNumber as String
        sNumber = CStr(Sheets(2).Range("A1").Value)  ' declare yourown address

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;E:\DANDY\FBI\ATM\Prima\ATM\1.Transaksi\Data Mentah\**" & sNumber & "**RP\" & sNumber & "B1S-RAW.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
            )
            ' rest of code
```

Comment: Sub Import_Approved()
Dim sNumber As String
    sNumber = CStr(Sheets("EKSEKUSI").Range("F2").Value)
Sheets("B1").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;E:\DANDY\FBI\ATM\Prima\ATM\1.Transaksi\Data Mentah\&sNumber&RPT\&sNumber&B1-RAW.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
        )                                when i input your code,vba error in line .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False